# Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error while importing the database in mysql, and when I resubmit the same file than I am getting this error

```
Error

SQL query:

-- -- Dumping data for table `adminnotification_inbox` -- INSERT INTO `adminnotification_inbox` (`notification_id`, `severity`, `date_added`, `title`, `description`, `url`, `is_read`, `is_remove`) VALUES (1, 4, '2008-07-25 05:24:17', 'Magento 1.1 Production Version Now Available', 'We are thrilled to announce the availability of the production release of Magento 1.1. Read more about the release in the Magento Blog.', 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/magento-11-is-here-1/', 0, 0), (2, 4, '2008-08-02 05:29:53', 'Updated iPhone Theme is now available', 'Updated iPhone theme for Magento 1.1 is now available on Magento Connect and for upgrade through your Magento Connect Manager.', 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/updated-iphone-theme-for-magento-11-is-now-available/', 0, 0), (3, 3, '2008-08-02 05:40:04', 'Magento version 1.1.2 is now available', 'Magento version 1.1.2 is now available for download and upgrade.', 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/mag[...]

MySQL said: Documentation
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

What should I do now. I already use the time increasing solutions given on the internet but nothing happen. How should I fix this error.

My database size is just only 3 MB. I am using xampp 1.8.3 in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: The field `notification_id` seems to be a primary key, which means it cannot have same values. Check if you already have value `1` for that field in the database or if it's repeating in your `.sql` file.

Comment: I checked for the field in the .sql file there is only a single entry for the `notification_id` there. I dont understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE adminnotification_inbox;
```

or

```
DELETE FROM adminnotification_inbox;
```

and then start anew

Comment: But I need that table in my database, how can I drop it.

Comment: After DROP you have to create it again, before inserting. Otherwise DELETE the content